# Socket bind always returns 0 on linux, even if the port is taken already

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

The following code returns 0 from the bind if run on Linux, even when netstat clearly shows that the port is taken by another process, ie the following function will always return true. Why?

```
bool isPortAvailable( int port ) 
    { 
        SOCKET candidateSocket; 

        if(( candidateSocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 )) == -1 ) 
            return false; 

        struct sockaddr_in serverAddress; 
        memset (&serverAddress, 0, sizeof (serverAddress)); 

        serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET; 
        serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( INADDR_ANY ); 
        serverAddress.sin_port = htons( port ); 

        if( ::bind( candidateSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof( serverAddress )) != 0 ) 
        { 
            closesocket( candidateSocket ); 
            return false; 
        } 

        closesocket( candidateSocket ); 
        return true; 
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the proper "bind"?  There's a bind function for "binding functions" and a bind function for binding network sockets.

Comment: Are you using socket option SO_REUSEADDR/SO_REUSEPORT and the other process is also owned by you?

Comment: I am sure I am using the bind for binding network sockets. In will return proper error messages for invalid ports, like 2.

Comment: The other process is owned by me, but I don't see REUSEADDR/PORT options on anywhere

Comment: Pause your code after the bind and verify that it is indeed bound to the intended host/port. This will eliminate coding errors where input is different that what was thought. Verify using standard linux tools such as `netstat`.

Comment: it is NOT bound at that point, at least netstat -lptu doesn't see it. But it still returned 0

Comment: You are absolutely correct that it isn't bound yet because it's not listening yet. But because your bind is not returning EADDRINUSE, I guess your only option is to call listen and check if it fails with EADDRINUSE. An ugly workaround I would say.

Comment: Alvits, thank you. And it will probably even work, but I feel like I should understand why bind doesn't fail like advertised.

Comment: I just noticed the `::` in your bind call. That might be misconstrued as what Happington said. Remove it and see if it helps.

Comment: removing :: didn't change anythinng.

Comment: added a listen call, it didn't change anything!

Comment: If I do use SO_REUSEPORT  somewhere that I just can't see at the moment, is there a way to make this bind NOT to use that option, explicitely?

Comment: If you happen to use SO_REUSEPORT unwittingly, you can disable it through `setsockopt()`. And `getsockopt()` will tell you the current options.

Comment: set SO_REUSEADDR to no (int no = 0), did a check on listen after bind. Still the same issue. I am begining to think I'm cursed!

Comment: I'm beginning to think the host has multiple addresses and the other app is listening on one address on the same port while this one, due to use of `INADDR_ANY`, is binding to an available address on the same port. Remember that conflict only occurs if the combination of IP:PORT is the same. If the IP part is different then there's no conflict. So if your host has both a.b.c.d and a.b.c.e then technically you can have 2 apps listening on port X as long as one is on a.b.c.d while the other is on a.b.c.e. Your code might even be using 127.0.0.1 while the other code is using the non-localhost IP.

Comment: Sometimes (at least on Windows, maybe Linux is the same), `bind()` may not have enough info to perform the actual binding right away, so the info is cached internally and a subsequent `listen()` or `connect()` is needed to finish the binding, at which time any failure is then reported, not on the `bind()` itself.

Comment: I thought multiple interfaces was the answer, but it's not :(

./$ sudo netstat -lptu |grep 190

tcp        0      0 localhost:19080             *:*                         LISTEN      12033/Test 

tcp        0      0 localhost:19080             *:*                         LISTEN      12033/Test

Comment: Might be worth adding the netstat output, properly formatted, to the question so that people can see that and eliminate it.

Comment: ./$ sudo netstat -lptu |grep 190
    tcp 0 0 localhost:19080 : LISTEN 12033/Test
    tcp 0 0 localhost:19080 : LISTEN 12033/Test

Comment: I'm sorry, formatting in this totally defeats me